# How can i get the users results and return 1 or 0 when they have a specific university?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel-5, eloquent

I have an application that needs to get the users details e.g) first name from the database, however for each user i want to join the university they choose when registering and check if **that university's ID** matches against **another external ID**. When true return 1 or 0 when false. I tried coming up with a solution buts i get errors.

My Query so far:

```
        DB::table('users')->select('users.first_name', 'universities.name', 'universities.state')
                      ->where('users.id', '!=', Auth::user()->id)
                      ->join('universities', function ($join) {
                          $join->on('users.university_id', '=', 'universities.id')
                               ->select(DB::raw('count(universities.id) as state'))
                               ->where('universities.id', '=', '$theExternalID')
                               ->groupBy('users.university_id');
                      })
                      ->get();
```

The query above still causes errors. Please help!

Comment: you must use EXIST

Comment: Thank you for your response, can you give me an example in this case with my kind of query

Comment: YELLING DOES NOT HELP.

Comment: You tagged laravel-eloquent, are you using Eloquent Relationships? https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships

Comment: I included the tag incase people with more experience can suggest other techniques, even if its done with eloquent in whatever way they suggest

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a one-to-one relationship between a user and a university.

User model:

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class University extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the University that is associated with the user.
     */
    public function university()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\University');
    }
}
```

University model:

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class University extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the users for the university.
     */
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

Then you can query where a user is associated with a university that matches the external ID:

```
User::university()->where('university_id', $theExternalID)->get();
```